How many solutions does this system have?
Let us consider the system of two transcendental equations x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0 &&  x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0 and its solutions belonging to
the square x1 >= -20 && x1 <= 20 && x2 >= -20 && x2 <= 20.
The plot
ContourPlot[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0}, {x1, -20, 20}, {x2, -20, 20}, 
PlotPoints -> 50]


suggests the number is big (It's  unclear even whether the set of the solutions is finite.).
These are my attempts.
NSolve[x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0 && 
x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0 && x1 >= -20 &&
x1 <= 20 && x2 >= -20 && x2 <= 20, {x1, x2}, Reals] // Dimensions


{195, 2}

and the warning "NSolve::incs: Warning: NSolve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete".
Splitting the square into smaller ones, I obtain
d = 5; Table[Dimensions[NSolve[x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0 && 
 x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0 && x1 >= k &&
x1 <= k + d && x2 >= n && x2 <= n + d, {x1, x2}, Reals]][[ 1]], {k, -20, 20 - d, d}, {n, -20, 20 - d, d}] // Flatten


{27, 28, 21, 2, 8, 23, 29, 33, 35, 31, 23, 0, 5, 25, 29, 29, 34, 28,  30, 26, 20, 30, 27, 32, 2, 0, 27, 9, 7, 0, 0, 20, 14, 15, 30, 10, 19,  19, 15, 16, 30, 34, 30, 4, 9, 31, 32, 30, 30, 32, 25, 0, 10, 26, 31,  27, 30, 25, 24, 14, 14, 25, 29, 33}

and the same warnings. The execution lasted a few hours since I can't efficiently use ParallelTable on my comp.
Total[%]


1353

The case d = 2; : the same warnings and 1580 solutions.
So the questions arise: how many solutions does this system have? how to deduce it?

Dealing with a partition function, we need to know its zeros.

Why not to add option  WorkingPrecision -> 30 to NSolve? :)

@AlexTrounev:NSolve[x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5  x1 - x2] == 0 &&     x2 - x2*Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2] + x1*Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2] == 0 &&     x1 >= -20 && x1 <= 20 && x2 >= -20 && x2 <= 20, {x1, x2}, Reals,    WorkingPrecision -> 25] // Dimensions results in the same {195, 2}.

Just a clarification question, do you want to count the root $x1=0, x2=\pi/2$ as a single or double root? I guess for partition function you need to take multiplicities into account, isn't it?

@yarchik: Thank you for your valuable question. Googling "zeros of partition function", I don't find an answer.

Concerning NSolve, the command NSolve[(2 - x^2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 == 0 && x >= -2 && x <= 2 && y >= -2 &&    y <= 2, {x, y}, Reals] returns {} and "NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with -((121001 x)/175984)-(92291 y)/87992 == 1".

The casesd=1; and d=1/2: only one warning and 1609 solutions in both cases. The executions take correspondently 15200.9s and 30202.6s.

Try ContourPlot and MeshFunctions  in order to estimate numerically the number of solutions:
f[x1_, x2_] := x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2]
g[x1_, x2_] := x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2]
picS = ContourPlot[{f[x1, x2] == 0(*, g[x1, x2] == 0*)}, {x1, - 20,20}, {x2, - 20, 20}, 
MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] &, f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &},Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Black,PlotPoints->200 ] (* needs ~20s to evaluate*)

The number of Point' s found in picS gives the number of intersections(solutions)
punkte = picS[[1, 1]][[1]];
pS = Cases[picS, Point[p_] :> punkte[[p]], -1][[1]];
Length[pS] (*1613 solutions*)

Show[ContourPlot[{f[x1, x2] == 0 , g[x1, x2] == 0 }, {x1, - 20,20}, {x2, - 20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 200], 
ListPlot[pS , PlotStyle -> {  PointSize[Medium], Black}]]


The result depends on the accuracy of ContourPlot (options PlotPoints, MaxRecursion)

+1. Thank you. This is helpful, though does not answer the question.

It gives an numerical estimation of the number of solutions, not more!

It does not seem like there should be 3226 points. I guess it is too much.

@azerbajdzan It looks like (if you zoom in ContourPlot)  Mathematica evaluates two nearby intersection points???

@UlrichNeumann I think so. There are many duplicates.

@azerbajdzan I modified my answer, now picS only plots f.  I get 1613 solutions.

@UlrichNeumann I found them 1599 so now it looks more reasonable. Maybe you could use PlotRangePadding -> 0 to ensure that no root near but outside the boundary is counted.

@azerbajdzan PlotRangePadding -> 0  doesn't change my result. How did you get your solution?

@UlrichNeumann Using FindRoot but I might have missed some roots as well. You could also check, whether some of your roots are outside of {-20,20} range.

Unfortunately, your code produces 1617 solutions when putting PlotPoints -> 220. Could this be called reliable?

1617 is a very good estimation I think.

With ' PlotPoints' to '240' again 1613.

Actually ContourPlot it is not a method to compute roots :)

But sometimes very helpful

We can try FindRoot as follows
h=1/4;grid = Range[-20, 20, h]; s = 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Flatten[ParallelTable[{x1, x2} /. 
     Quiet@FindRoot[
       x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5  x1 - x2] == 0 && 
        x2 - x2*Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2] + x1*Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2] == 0, {{x1,
          grid[[i]]}, {x2, grid[[j]]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {i, 
     Length[grid]}, {j, Length[grid]}], 1]

In this example we have
s // Dimensions

Out[]= {10313, 2}

But some of the roots lie outside the region Rectangle[{-20, -20}, {20, 20}]. Then we can decries step size from h=1/4 to h=1/8 and increase from 1/4 to 1/2 and look if there is convergence. For h=1/2 we have  {3855, 2}, and for h=1/8 we have {34175, 2} (it takes about 12m on my Silver Pentium). As we can see there is no convergence at all. Therefore, we need some deep analytical research, since number of roots increases with h decreases - see Figure below.

Using Select we can take roots from Rectangle[{-20, -20}, {20, 20}] only,
s0 = Select[s, Abs[#[[1]]] <= 20 && Abs[#[[2]]] <= 20 &]

For this number we have
s0 // Dimensions

Out[]= {9085, 2}

For h=1/2,1/8 numbers are {3423, 2}, and {30484, 2} consequently. Roots shown below

Update 1. To find all branches and exclude some of them we use Reduce as follows
 Reduce[{x1 - x1*Sin[a] - x2*Cos[b] == 0, 
  x2 - x2*Sin[c] + x1*Cos[d] == 0}, {x1, x2}]

Out[]= (Sin[c] == 1 && x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 && 
   Cos[b] Cos[d] != 0) || (Sin[c] == 1 && Cos[b] == 0 && x1 == 0 && 
   Cos[d] != 0) || (Sin[c] == 1 && Cos[d] == 0 && Cos[b] != 0 && 
   x2 == Sec[b] (x1 - x1 Sin[a])) || (Sin[c] == 1 && Sin[a] == 1 && 
   Cos[d] == 0 && Cos[b] == 0) || (Cos[d] != 0 && 
   Cos[b] == 
    Sec[d] (-1 + Sin[a] + Sin[c] - Sin[a] Sin[c]) && -1 + Sin[c] != 
    0 && x2 == (x1 Cos[d])/(-1 + Sin[c])) || (-1 + Sin[c] != 0 && 
   Sin[a] == 1 && Cos[d] == 0 && 
   x2 == 0) || (1 + Cos[b] Cos[d] - Sin[a] - Sin[c] + Sin[a] Sin[c] !=
     0 && x1 == 0 && -1 + Sin[c] != 0 && x2 == 0) || (Sin[c] == 1 && 
   Cos[d] == 0 && Cos[b] == 0 && -1 + Sin[a] != 0 && x1 == 0)

Where {a = x1 + 5*x2, b = 5 x1 - x2, c = 5 x1 - 3 x2, d = 3 x1 + 5 x2}. First 4 branches describe trivial solution $x1=0, x2=0$. We interested in nontrivial solution that described by branch 5
(Cos[d] != 0 && 
  Cos[b] == 
   Sec[d] (-1 + Sin[a] + Sin[c] - Sin[a] Sin[c]) && -1 + Sin[c] != 0 &&
   x2 == (x1 Cos[d])/(-1 + Sin[c]))

As we can see it is a nontrivial solution of homogenous linear system with zero discriminant that we can represent with
{vec, mat} = 
 CoefficientArrays[{x1 - x1*Sin[a] - x2*Cos[b] == 0, 
   x2 - x2*Sin[c] + x1*Cos[d] == 0}, {x1, x2}]; 
mat // Normal

(*Out[]= {{1 - Sin[a], -Cos[b]}, {Cos[d], 1 - Sin[c]}}*)
With[{a = x1 + 5*x2, b = 5 x1 - x2, c = 5 x1 - 3 x2, 
  d = 3 x1 + 5 x2}, Det[{{1 - Sin[a], -Cos[b]}, {Cos[d], 1 - Sin[c]}}]]

Out[]= 1 + Cos[5 x1 - x2] Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] - Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] - 
 Sin[x1 + 5 x2] + Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] Sin[x1 + 5 x2]

Finally we can compute nontrivial roots with FindRoot using norm of equations to select right solutions
grid1 = Range[-20, 20, 1]; snorm1 = 
 Flatten[ParallelTable[{x1, x2, 
     Norm[{1 + Cos[5 x1 - x2] Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] - Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] - 
        Sin[x1 + 5 x2] + Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] Sin[x1 + 5 x2], 
       x2 - (x1 Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2])/(-1 + Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2])}]} /. 
    Quiet@FindRoot[{1 + Cos[5 x1 - x2] Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] - 
         Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] - Sin[x1 + 5 x2] + 
         Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] Sin[x1 + 5 x2] == 0, 
       x2 - (x1 Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2])/(-1 + Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2]) == 0}, {{x1,
         grid1[[i]]}, {x2, grid1[[j]]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {i, 
    Length[grid1]}, {j, Length[grid1]}], 1]

Selection
sol1 = DeleteDuplicates@Select[snorm1, #[[3]] < 10^-16 &];

 Length[sol1]

(*Out[]= 425*)

Using 4 grids with h=1,1/2,1/4,1/8 we plot results as

As we can see number of roots increasing with h decreasing even we select the reliable solutions only with norm of equations <10^-16.
Update 2 Ignoring small differences we can select roots as follows
grid = Range[-20, 20, #] & /@ {1/5, 1/10}; 
snorm[k_] := 
 Flatten[ParallelTable[{x1, x2, 
     Norm[{1 + Cos[5  x1 - x2]  Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2] - 
        Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2] - Sin[x1 + 5  x2] + 
        Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2]  Sin[x1 + 5  x2], 
       x2 - (x1  Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2])/(-1 + Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2])}]} /. 
    Quiet@FindRoot[{1 + Cos[5  x1 - x2]  Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2] - 
         Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2] - Sin[x1 + 5  x2] + 
         Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2]  Sin[x1 + 5  x2] == 0, 
       x2 - (x1  Cos[3  x1 + 5  x2])/(-1 + Sin[5  x1 - 3  x2]) == 
        0}, {{x1, grid[[k, i]]}, {x2, grid[[k, j]]}}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30], {i, Length[grid[[k]]]}, {j, 
    Length[grid[[k]]]}], 1]


 sol = snorm[#] & /@ {1, 2}; // AbsoluteTiming

sol1 = 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Select[sol[[1]], #[[3]] < 10^-16 && Abs[#[[1]]] <= 20 && 
     Abs[#[[2]]] <= 20 &]; Length[sol1]

(*Out[]= 2462*)

 sol2 = 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Select[sol[[2]], #[[3]] < 10^-16 && Abs[#[[1]]] <= 20 && 
     Abs[#[[2]]] <= 20 &]; Length[sol2]

(*Out[]= 5522*)

Now we apply filter to select unique roots and so ignoring multiple roots
sol11 = DeleteDuplicates[sol1, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-15 &]

sol21 = DeleteDuplicates[sol2, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-15 &] 
Length[#] & /@ {sol11, sol21}

Out[]= {1385, 1421}

These numbers look as reasonable and maybe we can reach number 1617 computed with other methods.

+1. Thank you for your work. However, it is difficult to call the results of FindRoot reliable. I also don't  understand the advantage of FindRoot over NSolve.

I tried FindRoot, and I have found some issues that you have overlooked. First, some solutions provided by FindRoot are not the roots of the original equation, you have to check them. Second, DeleteDuplicates  cannot delete the same root because they could be near but not the same. Instead, I use DeleteDuplicates[#, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-10 &] &.

@JieZhu Clever! If I apply your suggestions there are 1617 solutions left!

@AlexTrounev If you add (see JieZhu's comment) s0 = Select[s, RealAbs[#[[1]]] < 20 && RealAbs[#[[2]]] < 20 &]; s1 = Select[s0,# . # &[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] ,    x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2]}] < 10^-10 /. {x1 -> #[[1]], x2 -> #[[2]]} & ]; s2 = DeleteDuplicates[     s1, (#1 - #2) . (#1 - #2) < 10^-10 &] ; // AbsoluteTiming  the result s2 consists of 1617 solutions.

@user64494 It is not advantage, this is local model  with possibilities to solve equations on a grid. Then with step size decreasing we can try to get number of roots. But solution is not converges. Therefore we need some analytical research to estimate number of roots.

@UlrichNeumann Why not to use (#1 - #2) . (#1 - #2) < 10^-20, taken into account that WorkingPrecision -> 30 ? :)

@JieZhu Why not to use DeleteDuplicates[#, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-24 &] & taken into account that WorkingPrecision -> 30? :)

@AlexTrounev Yes of course

@AlexTrounev So what is your conclusion? How many roots are there? Your method is not correct as you use Quiet that just ignores warning messages. With each warning message you introduce another incorrect root, so there is no surprise that number of your found  "roots" increases . But that was already pointed out in the comment by Jie Zhu.

@azerbajdzan You don't pay attention that I used norm of equations to test solutions, therefore, with my method we compute all roots with error less than 10^-16, it is much better then that with NSolve as in your answer or with ContourPlot . My conclusion is that we can't numerically define number of roots, so we need some analytical research. :)

@AlexTrounev Again, have you read the comment by Jie Zhu? Your DeleteDuplicates in last section "Selection" is there probably for decoration because it does nothing. Do you understand how DeleteDuplicates works? Do it properly by the code provided in  Jie Zhu's comment. Your final result is full of duplicates that were not properly deleted. For example with h=1 the root sol1[[6]] is same as root sol1[[25]], yet you take it as two separate roots.

@azerbajdzan No, you are not right. You can test that DeleteDuplicates really deletes some duplicates, and that sol1[[6]]  and sol1[[25]] difference is of about 10^-29, while  WorkingPrecision -> 30.    We can count these roots as duplicate follow by our imagination, but not numerically. We don't know maybe there are several roots with small difference. From the other side if use very rough  estimation proposed by Jie Zhu in a form  DeleteDuplicates[#, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-10 &] & then why we need  WorkingPrecision -> 30 ? :)

@AlexTrounev Oh boy, you really do not understand what precision means. Evaluate FindRoot[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0,    x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0},   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{{x1, x2}, sol1[[6, {1, 2}]]}]],   WorkingPrecision -> 1000] FindRoot[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0,    x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0},   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{{x1, x2}, sol1[[25, {1, 2}]]}]],   WorkingPrecision -> 1000] to see that roots sol1[[6]] and sol1[[25]] are the same.

@azerbajdzan Actually I don't understand what do you try to do? Are you trying to force me to use a rough roots estimate to get the same result as you? :)

You say sol1[[6]] and sol1[[25]] are two different roots... Then give me them with accuracy of 100 digits. Can you do that? Post it here...

@azerbajdzan Sorry, but you seem to have confused the results of the numerical model and my thoughts about it. :) Okay, I'll try filtering the roots to see if there is convergence in this case.

@azerbajdzan Maybe it is just "a special russian precision", and some roots are not duplicates but instead call them "special roots". :-D

@three777 Do you mean "a special Canadian precision" since I am in Toronto now. :)

@azerbajdzan Can you prove that these 2 roots are the same instead of just bothering me?

@three777 Fortunately I am not obligated to use word "special" to obfuscate the true nature of just ordinary mistake.

@AlexTrounev This is not how it works in math. It is YOU who has to prove that they are two distinct roots because it is your assertion that they are distinct, but you still have not showed us the 100 digits of the "two purported roots".

@azerbajdzan Maybe you have answer to the yarchik's question "do you want to count the root sol1[[6]], sol[[25]]  as a single or double root"? :)

This is a exact and "error/warning-messages-free" method.
Firstly, there are roots that can be expressed exactly as {x1, x2} -> {(4 m - n) Pi/2, (1 + n) Pi/2}. I am not going into detail how I found them as it is not necessary for the answer to the question. But we can verify it by:
FullSimplify[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
   x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0} /. 
  Thread[{x1, x2} -> {(4 m - n) Pi/2, (1 + n) Pi/2}], 
 Assumptions -> Element[{m, n}, Integers]]


{True, True}

Some of those exact roots are singular, namely those with x1==0 or x2==0. These singular roots are the cause of problems when trying to find a root around these singular points.
The next code searches for roots in squares m <= x1 < m + 1, n <= x2 < n + 1 if it takes longer than 1 second the region is added to fail if not the found roots are added to roots.
Those failed region are regions that contain singular roots so then we search again those regions but avoiding x1==0 or x2==0. Those roots are added to rootsavoid.
Finally we search for singular roots in failed regions by explicitly setting x1==0 or x2==0. These roots are added to rootssingular.
Then all found roots are joined in allroots = Join[roots, rootsavoid, rootssingular].
The length of allroots is 1617 surprisingly exactly same as @UlrichNeumann's answer (when PlotPoints -> 220 is used).
The code monitors {m,n}. At output we see failed regions and total number of roots.
Clear[m, n]
roots = {};
fail = {};
Monitor[Do[
  TimeConstrained[
   AppendTo[roots, 
    NSolve[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
      x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0, 
      m <= x1 < m + 1, n <= x2 < n + 1}]], 1, 
   AppendTo[fail, {m, n}]], {m, -20, 19}, {n, -20, 19}], {m, n}]
roots = Values[Flatten[roots, 1]];
fail

avoidzero = fail /. {-1 -> -1 - 1/1000, 0 -> 0 + 1/1000};
rootsavoid = 
  Flatten[NSolve[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
        x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0, 
        m <= x1 < m + 1, n <= x2 < n + 1} /. Thread[{m, n} -> #]] & /@
     avoidzero, 1];

singular = fail /. {-1 -> 0} // Union;
rootssingular = 
  Flatten[Join[
     NSolve[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
          x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0, 
          x1 == 0, n <= x2 < n + 1} /. Thread[{m, n} -> #]] & /@ 
      Cases[singular, {0, _}], 
     NSolve[{x1 - x1*Sin[x1 + 5*x2] - x2*Cos[5 x1 - x2] == 0, 
          x2 - x2*Sin[5 x1 - 3 x2] + x1*Cos[3 x1 + 5 x2] == 0, 
          m <= x1 < m + 1, x2 == 0} /. Thread[{m, n} -> #]] & /@ 
      Cases[singular, {_, 0}]], 1] // Values;

allroots = Join[roots, rootsavoid, rootssingular];
Length[allroots]


{{-18, -1}, {-18, 0}, {-11, -1}, {-11, 0}, {-5, -1}, {-5, 
  0}, {-1, -18}, {-1, -11}, {-1, -5}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 7}, {-1, 
  14}, {0, -18}, {0, -11}, {0, -5}, {0, 1}, {0, 7}, {0, 
  14}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {7, -1}, {7, 0}, {14, -1}, {14, 0}}

1617


Thank you for your work. As I understand it, some solutions are of the form {(4 m - n) Pi/2, (1 + n) Pi/2}  with Element[{m, n}, Integers] and  you find other solutions numerically.   Can you kindly elaborate your "Some of those exact roots are singular, namely those with x1==0 or x2==0. These singular roots are the cause of problems when trying to find a root around these singular points", giving us details? Concerning the comparison with the UlrichNeumann's answer, if  PlotPoints -> 240 are taken, I obtain 1613 solutions by his code and this is noticed in my comment to his answer.

+1 for the exact solutions. I don't see in your answer any proof that all the solutions of the system under consideration in x1 >= -20 && x1 <= 20 && x2 >= -20 && x2 <= 20 are found by you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve

Sorry, I don't find your reply satisfactory. What type are singular points of? Is the set of 1617 solutions  found by you complete?

There are some acnodes and crunodes. Numerical methods fail on such points. Yes, the set is complete - you do not seem to understand the code when you are asking.

@azerbajdzan Nice attempt (+1), but I think that we can't compute all roots with NSolve. See Update 1 to my answer with FindRoot application on 4 grids.

@AlexTrounev Surely we can when used wisely. Give me a root that is missing in my list of 1617 roots stored in the variable allroots.

@azerbajdzan: You wrote "Yes, the set is complete - you do not seem to understand the code when you are asking". Sorry, I prefer arguments over empty words.

@azerbajdzan The grid form your "guessed" analytical solution is much smaller than the grid you use in your following calculation ...,{m,-20,19},{n,-20,19}] , I don't understand why that should be correct

@UlrichNeumann The analytical solution is not necessary (it exists so I provided it, among these analytical roots there are some singular, that was the reason why I mentioned them). All the roots are then found numerically in the region {x1, -20, 20}, {x2, -20, 20} which is subdivided into squares {x1, m, m+1}, {x2, n, n+1} for {m, -20, 19}, {n, -20, 19}. I really do not see what you have problem with.

@azerbajdzan Though you choose an arbitray grid , with roughly 1600 rectangles, where you try to detect possible solutions. If you refine your grid, what happens with the number of solutions? Unfortunately I cannot run your code because I use Mathematica v12.2 and NSolve doesn't return results.

@UlrichNeumann The result of course does not change with changing the grid. Only the timing can change. If the region is too large with many roots NSolve needs much more time. With 1x1 grid there are not too many roots and time needed is quite small.

@UlrichNeumann Do you want the list allroots from my code? I can add it to my answer. You can check whether you can find a root that is missing in my list.

@azerbajdzan Thanks, no that's not necessary. I 'll try to modify your code changing NDSolve to FindRoot
